# not able to convert dynamic url to static url via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting my problem .
Below I am giving all the details of what i am trying to do, and what is the result I am getting. I hope to be very clear this time. I have a samples page here www.broadcast2world.com/samples.php. 
All the links and data which we see on the page is coming from a database. Now suppose we click on a link "More Info" for a particular video say social control. A specific href for that video is triggered as `<a href="video.php?pid='.$id.'">` . It passes its id over url in the format `http://www.broadcast2world.com/video.php?pid=66.`

I catch that id into a variable using

```
if(!isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $pageid='66';
}
else{
  $pageid=$_GET['pid'];  
}
```

Using the $pageid variable, I run a query which ultimately prepare the page for that particular video.

What my SEO guy need is a url in the format www.broadcast2world.com/video/name-of-the-video.

Now the problem is that if I make a mod_rewrite amendments which is wonderfully explained by Ben below, I am not able to figure out, how to link that name-of-the-video to its id. I am sure there must be something I have to modify while creating specific url for videos as explained above. But I really don't know what? Thanks again for your wonderful support

Comment: Hi Ben,Many Thanks for the followup.I have not been able to configure it properly yet . I think I am missing something when I am generating the url, which is still in ?query format. I was afraid to ask about that, because last time when I did, many of the contributors had down-voted and ridiculed me. Is it okay if I could message you with exactly what I am doing?

Comment: Hi Ben, I get your point. I am re-editing the question and I hope to make myself much more clear this time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with the .htaccess code generated by that website.

- The period character (`.`) should be escaped on the left hand side of RewriteRule directives - i.e. `\.php`.
- The query string isn't taken into account (This is the primary cause of your problem which I explain below).
- There's no indication of the type of redirect used. Temporary? Permanent?
- There's no `RewriteBase` directive. Not essential as `/` is taken as the default, but for readability's sake, I tend to use it.

Rewrite directives notably take into account only the REQUEST_URI component. The below is from the [mod_rewrite manual page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

> REQUEST_URI The path component of the requested URI, such as
>   "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is
>   available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

The following code is explained in the comments, and debugging info from here can be found below.

```
# Enable rewrite engine http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine
RewriteEngine On

# Sets the base URL for per-directory rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
RewriteBase /

# Match the regular expression ^pname=...$ with the QUERY_STRING variable as the subject
# Query string starts with pname (`^`). 
# Matches exactly pname=overviewvideos.
# Must end with overviewvideos (`$`)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pname=overvidevideos$

# If the above condition is met, redirect to the 2nd parameter.
# Note the escaped period (\.)
# Note the status code 302 (Found, temporary) Can be 301 for permanent etc.
# Note the L flag - this prevents further rules being processed if the conditions are met. (L for Last)
# Note that at this stage we are back to matching the REQUEST_URI, so just allvideos.php in our regular expression. Must start and end with the string allvideos.php
RewriteRule ^allvideos\.php$ allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos [R=302,L]
```

Input URL: http://www.yoursite.com/allvideos.php?pname=overvidevideos

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pname=overvidevideos$  This condition was met
RewriteRule ^allvideos\.php$ allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos [R=302,L]    
    This rule was met, the new url is http://www.yoursite.com/allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos
    Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. A redirect will be made with status code 302
```

Output URL: http://www.yoursite.com/allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos

To repeat the rules, you can duplicate the lines beginning RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line

```
RewriteRule ^allvideos.php/pname=overviewvideos$ allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos
```

With the below code

```
RewriteRule ^allvideos.php?pname=overviewvideos$ allvideos.php?pname=Overview%20Videos
```

Note the replacement of the `/` with a `?`

Similarly make the same alteration to the 2nd rewrite rule